# LWC - Form data to the controller

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components

I am trying to create a LWC that will pass the data from fields in the form into the apex controller. Is there a way that I can pass all of the values from the form to the APEX Controller?
When I try and pass the form data into the APEX Controller it is coming back as Null in the debugger. Below is the code.

APEX Controller

```
public with sharing class clsQuoteRevisionLWC {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=false)   
public static void QuoteRevision(SBQQ__Quote__c Quote){
 system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'Start clsQuoteRevisionLWC = Quote            ' +  Quote);
 system.debug(logginglevel.debug, 'Start clsQuoteRevisionLWC = Quote            ' +  Quote.id);

  }
}
```

JavaScript

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire, track } from 'lwc';
const FIELDS = ['SBQQ__Quote__c.Application__c','SBQQ__Quote__c.Name'];
import { getRecord } from 'lightning/uiRecordApi';
import { NavigationMixin } from 'lightning/navigation';
import CreateQuoteRevision from '@salesforce/apex/clsQuoteRevisionLWC.QuoteRevision';
import QUOTE_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/SBQQ__Quote__c';

export default class LwcQuoteRevision extends NavigationMixin(LightningElement)  {
activeSections = ['A', 'C'];
@api recordId;
@track QuoteRecord = {};

handleSubmit(event) {
    console.log('onsubmit event recordEditForm'+ { ...this.QuoteRecord, sobjectType: QUOTE_OBJECT.objectApiName } );

  //  CreateQuoteRevision({ Quote: { ...this.QuoteRecord, sobjectType: QUOTE_OBJECT.objectApiName } })
    CreateQuoteRevision({ Quote: { ...this.QuoteRecord, sobjectType: 'SBQQ__Quote__c' } })

}
handleSuccess(event) {
    console.log('onsuccess event recordEditForm', event.detail.id);
}
}
```

HTML

```
 <template>
<lightning-record-edit-form record-id={recordId} object-api-name="SBQQ__Quote__c"
onsuccess={handleSuccess} onsubmit ={handleSubmit}>

<lightning-messages></lightning-messages>

 <lightning-accordion allow-multiple-sections-open
  active-section-name={activeSections}>
  <lightning-accordion-section name="A" label="Quote Information">

<div class="slds-grid slds-wrap slds-p-around--medium" style="background:#eee; border:1px #ddd solid;">
<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-output-field field-name="Name"></lightning-output-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Application__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Short_Description_of_Quote__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Channel_Type__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="SBQQ__Type__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Quote_Expiration_Date_Explanation__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Original_Quote__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Currency"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="SBQQ__Account__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="Internal_Order_Status_Notes__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="SBQQ__Opportunity2__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>

<div class="slds-col slds-size_6-of-12 slds-p-horizontal_medium">
    <lightning-input-field field-name="erpid__c"></lightning-input-field>
</div>   

<lightning-button class="slds-m-top_small" variant="brand" type="submit" name="update" label="Update"></lightning-button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QuoteRecord object is in no way linked to the lightning-record-edit-form, so there's no way you could get the data to the server. You need to copy the values to the variable before you could possibly use it.

```
handleSubmit(event) {
  Object.assign(
    this.QuoteRecord, 
    event.detail.fields, 
    { sobjectType: QUOTE_OBJECT.objectApiName }
  );
  CreateQuoteRevision({Quote:this.QuoteRecord});
}
```

Comment: hmm, so if i do it with Object.Assign It throws an Error in APEX on the Debug log of Attempt to de-reference a null Object

Comment: @CodeMonger Yeah, just realized I screwed up the method call; it should be an Object that contains the parameters. Keep in mind also, everything in the JavaScript is case-sensitive. I've made an edit to reflect this.